# Export Multiple Groups to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory-group

I have a little script that exports a certain group to a csv file.

The question is if it is possible to insert a split in the group name to export twp groups into two separate csv files.

```
param (
 [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyname)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [string]$GroupName
)

Get-ADGroupMember -identity “$GroupName” | select-object SamAccountName | Export-csv -path C:\Report\$GroupName.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Is it possible to write `" Group1 Group2 "` and the export to two files, `Group1.csv` and `Group2.csv`?

Comment: `$a = $GroupName.trim().split(" ")` will give u an array of split items. Then `$a[0]` will give u `Group1` and `$a[1]` will give u `Group2`. So technically, you can send it to different csv

Comment: Foreach group in group, Get-ADGroupMember -identity “$GroupName”  export-csv $groupname+.csv  export multible files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
param (
 [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyname)]
 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [string]$GroupName
)
$allGroupNames = $GroupName -split " "
foreach( $GN in $allGroupNames ) {
    Get-ADGroupMember -identity “$GN” | select-object SamAccountName | Export-csv -path C:\Report\$GN.csv -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

Comment: Nice, but please don't use curly quotes `“` in code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just tried it but it doesn't work :( It saves only group1 group2.csv

Comment: you are a genius and i was wrong, i miss-pasted if you can believe that... Thank you so much!!!